# Integers a,b,c satisfying a+b+c|ab+bc+ca

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all integers $a,b,c$ such that
> $a+b+c|ab+ac+bc$

My progress: let's put $ab+ac+bc = ka+kb+kc$ and it's evaluate to $a(b+c-k)= kb +kc-bc$ and it's evaluate $b+c-k|kb+kc-bc$ and it's again evaluate to $b+c-k|bc-kc-kb$
It's obvious that it's exactly the for of the original division by considering $(b,c,-k)=(b,c,-(ab+ac+bc)/a+b+c))$
By idea here was to use vieta jumping by setting $f(x,y,z)=|xys|$

Comment: Hmm.... $(a+b+c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2+ 2(ab + ac + bc)$ so if $a+b+c|ab+bc+cd$ then $a+b+c|a^2 + b^2 + c^2$.  Don't know if that helps.

Comment: One infinite family is given by $(1,n,n^2)$ for any $n\in \mathbb N$. That;s not all of them...$(2,5,6)$ and $(2,3,14)$ are also examples.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617975/find-all-integer-solutions-to-abcabbccaabc).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Not a duplicate, I don't think. This only asks for solutions to $a + b + c | ab + bc + ca$, which are more numerous than ones such that $a + b + c | ab + bc + ca | abc$

Comment: @eyeballfrog Therefore I didn't vote for closing as a duplicate. But still, several proof ideas can be used here, too.

Comment: I feel this question should not be closed. This person is new here and asked a consistant question. There is a similar but distinct question. I do feel that perhaps the OP should explain things a little more. Or maybe its just me.

Comment: Using the parametric solution of $a^2+b^2+c^2=n(a+b+c)$ for $(a,b,c)$, the problem can be solved.